# Where can I find a list of Prolog commands?

Tags: date, prolog, command, tuprolog

I'm new to Prolog and trying to do a program to check if some values can be a date, but I don't know what can I do with the language. I don't know the commands.

As example, I want to get the length of a string, but I don't know if this is possible.

Someone can show me a list of Prolog commands? I'm using tuProlog for Java.

By the way, the program I want to do is this: receive two or three parameters and check if is some type of date (eg.: 10/2000, 2011/09, 11/03/1191, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sics.se/isl/sicstuswww/site/documentation.html) for [SICStus Prolog](http://www.sics.se/isl/sicstuswww/site/index.html) describes its standard library. I'm not entirely sure what parts of it are or aren't standard for a Prolog implementation, but it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the User guide for tuProlog [at this location](http://apice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/Documents)
Section 4.4 addresses builtin predicates.

This link might also be of help.
[Working with strings in Prolog](http://obvcode.blogspot.com/2008/11/working-with-strings-in-prolog.html)

And for parsing, given that one of the libraries in tuProlog is for DCGs:
[Prolog DCG presentation](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/255/lec/subject-prolog_dcg.pdf)

You can also search Stackoverflow for Prolog and dcg to see others' questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

tuProlog's user guide is easy to find: [Documentation](http://alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/Documents). Chapter 5 contains the Prolog commands at your disposal.

From your question, I infer that you receive the date as a string and you're not sure in which format the date string arrives.

I would look at `text_term/2` to transform the string into a term (I'm not 100% sure, the Prolog system I use has a differently named predicate for that). Then you can test whether it contains one or two slashes (or is in another format or is not a date at all), by unifying Term with a Term of the desired structure:

```
Term = D/M/Y
```

and testing if this is a valid date:

```
text_term(Text,Term),
( Term = D/M/Y, valid_date(D,M,Y) ->
  true
; Term = M/D/Y, valid_date(D,M,Y) ->
  true
; ...
```

The `->` is "if-then", the `;` is "else".
You'll need to write a predicate that test for valid dates, which I called `valid_date/3` above.